# Does it matter what versions of Angular third party modules installed via npm use?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic4

I have an Ionic4 app using the most current version of Angular7. I installed a few node modules from third parties via npm install --save. The npm modules I installed via npm use Angular4 (when I look through the modules package.json on git), but my main Ionic app uses Angular7. Am I using 2 versions of Angular in my Ionic app and bloating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simply answer is no, it doesnt matter what version of angular third party vendors use. Generally if a library how built using Angular 4 it can be consumed in an newer version of Angular eg) v6, v7 etc. One thing to look out for is the packages that you are consuming in your application, if a package was built with Angular 4 its a high possibility it contains other dependencies that was used and in some cases those packages that were used to build that library may come up as deprecated in newer versions of Angular.

To answer your comment, the answer is yes again; generally if you are using a newer version of Angular you should use the newer packages but if you do use a library that uses an older package, angular will adapt to the specification of that particular package.

Mark as answer is it helped, thank you.

IMPORTANT* when you are upgrading from the current version of angular to an advanced one, you should always install (using NPM install) the angular libraries first and only then the third party packages otherwise it could stuck your installation process and give you strange 'gyp-node' errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think your app is working because ionic was made out of angular, as far as i know, one thing i could recommend to you, apart from the fact that you are asking one thing on the title of your question and then asking something else on your description, is to use NVM.
Stuff like angular, npm and ionic will be linked to your node version, so you could work with two different versions of node and all of the other stuff will not get mixed up, i really hope this helps you a little.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if there is a standard way people just use the latest version of Angular and have the npm modules that I install as I develop just use the same version rather than the version in each modules specific package.json?